# Can't select from a dropdown menu with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

Im really struggling with selecting an item from a drop down menu on a site I'm trying to scrape. The code for the HTML is shown below:

```
<select id="averagesMP" name="MP" onchange="reQuery(this);" style="width: 150px">
       <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I've tried everything I can think of and find on StackOverflow! I've noticed that this seems to work to select the actual drop down box:

```
select_mp = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='MP']"))
```

but I only assume that works because the code runs and doesn't give any errors. However, I still can't select anything from the dropdown menu. I've tried:

- find_element_by_xpath/name/id/tag/value/text
- select_mp.select_by_value('2')
- select_mp.select_by_visible_text('2')
- select_mp.select_by_index(2)
- driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='MP']/option[@value='4']").click()
- driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='4']").click()
- driver.find_element_by_id('averagesMP').click()

Does anyone have any advice? I know that this question seems to get asked alot on here, but I've tried everything I've seen in a post and its not working! It doesn't seem like a very complicated dropdown menu, only very elusive.

Some helpful info:

- I'm using Safari and SafariDriver
- I keep getting an error message of:

  ```
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
  ```

Comment: Check if dropdown  is in iframe? If not then you might have to try javascriptexecutor.

Comment: What website is it on>?

Comment: the site is skedula.com. Its a grading website for teachers.

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<option>` with text as **2** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#averagesMP[@name='MP']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('2')
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_value()` in a single line:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='averagesMP' and @name='MP']")))).select_by_value('2')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! It looks like using XPATH is trying to access it, but now I'm getting the following error:

Message: Element <select id="averagesMP" name="MP"> is not clickable at point (465,59) because another element <div class="topContent"> obscures it

Does this mean that something is blocking the drop down menu I'm trying to access?